# Firebase custom auth provider I don't control/have access to?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use a custom authentication provider which I don't have any control over?

I develop an app in addition to a teachable course. Teachable is a platform like shopify where you can create online courses.

I want to use it as an auth provider, so a user, that already has an account can login with his teachable account.

To my knowledge custom authentications with auth tokes work like this: I send a request to my server with the entered user credentials. From my server I use these credential to login to teachable, if that was successful my server gets a callback and I return a token to my client, so the login was successful.

However as far as I know teachable doesn't have an api option for me to login and get a callback if it was successful.

What can I do about this? Also are there any security issues I didn't realized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the flow to add a custom provider to Firebase Authentication is correct. You need to be able get the authenticated token from the provider, and mint a Firebase custom token from it.

If the provider you're looking to add doesn't have an API, you won't be able to add it as a custom provider to Firebase though.

I don't immediately see another way to connect the provider without an API.